# What are some possible reasons for "Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability" happens only in Android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-security

Based on https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009, we implement "Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability" detection in our code.

We are getting crash log from Google Play Console, as we run `throw new SecurityException("https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009");` explicitly when we encounter **"Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability"**.

Currently, sometimes, I have **"Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability"** happens only in Android 11.

```
public static boolean extractZipFile(InputStream inputStream, String destDirectory, boolean overwrite) {
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = null;
    boolean status = true;

    try {
        zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
        final byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

                if (zipEntry == null) {
                    break;
                }

                final File destination = new File(destDirectory, zipEntry.getName());
                final String canonicalPath = destination.getCanonicalPath();
                if (!canonicalPath.startsWith(destDirectory)) {
                    throw new SecurityException("https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009");
                }
```

I always ensure `destDirectory` is non null, before calling `extractZipFile`

```
public static boolean extractZipFile(InputStream inputStream, boolean overwrite) {
    String destDirectory = Utils.getUserDataDirectory();
    if (destDirectory == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return extractZipFile(inputStream, destDirectory, overwrite);
}

public static String getUserDataDirectory() {
    if (externalFilesDir == null) {
        File _externalFilesDir = JStockApplication.instance().getExternalFilesDir(null);
        externalFilesDir = _externalFilesDir;
        if (externalFilesDir == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    return toEndWithFileSeperator(externalFilesDir.toString()) + getApplicationVersionString() + File.separator;
}

private static String toEndWithFileSeperator(String string) {
    if (string.endsWith(File.separator)) {
        return string;
    }
    return string + File.separator;
}

public static String getApplicationVersionString() {
    return "1.0.7";
}
```

Based on the posed source code, do you have any guess reason, why  "Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability" happens only in Android 11? I use emulator Android 11 but not able to reproduce the problem.

---

### Where does the zip file come from?

The zip file comes from 2 places

Bundled with APK as shown in below screenshot

[image]

We use the following code to extract it during runtime.

```
private void initPreloadDatabase(boolean overWrite) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("database" + File.separator + "database.zip");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
    if (inputStream != null) {
        org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.extractZipFile(inputStream, overWrite);
    }
}
```

Another zip file is downloaded from

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yccheok/jstock/master/appengine/jstock-android-static/war/stocks_information/unitedstate/stocks.zip

Comment: "The input zip file is bundled together with my APK. So, it doesn't contain any malicious path." -- since the APK is already a ZIP, do you need a ZIP inside a ZIP? "I have "Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability" happens only in Android 11" -- where and how are you getting that message?

Comment: I have updated the question to make thing clearer. Sorry.

Comment: You might want to revise that exception message, to include what `canonicalPath` and `destDirectory` are. In terms of the version-specific nature of the problem, perhaps there were changes in how `getCanonicalPath()` works (though then I would expect consistent failures, not sporadic ones).

Comment: The problem is, in Google Play Console, the user message included in exception is being removed (I think due to privacy reason). Firebase Crashlytics unable to capture such, because the exception happen in remote service, and Firebase Crashlytics doesn't seem to work in remote service.

Answer (score 0):

In `Utils.getUserDataDirectory()` function use:

```
getFilesDir().getCanonicalFile()
```

instead of

```
getExternalFilesDir()
```

Comment: do you know how to verify if this is fixed with the above change?

Comment: Something like that:
<code>
String canonicalPath = f.getCanonicalPath();

if (!canonicalPath.startsWith(Utils.getUserDataDirectory())) {
      throw new Exception(String.format("Found Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability with %s", canonicalPath));
}
</code>